# Isolated singularities: removable vs poles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I understand what the singularities are, but I am having trouble establishing them in what I feel is a formal fashion. Take these two questions I am working on.

$$\frac{z^4 - 2z^2 + 1}{(z-2)^2} $$  and $$\pi cot(\pi z)$$

Now to determine what type of singularity I have, I need to take the limit of the absolute value of my functions at the point where the singularity may occur. In these examples it would be at $z = 2$ and $z = n,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, respectively. My problem is this: I could see intuitively that in the first example the function is going to end up becoming indeterminate (e.g. $\frac{0}{0}$) while in the second example it is going to be something like $\frac{1}{0}$. Are these forms enough to determine whether the absolute value of my function is bounded or not? Or would i need to state something more?

Comment: Why do you think the first would become indeterminate? $2^4 - 2 \cdot 2^2 + 1 = 9 \neq 0$. If you get something like $\frac{1}{0}$, however, that's a pole, while "$\frac{0}{0}$" can be pole or removable, depends on whether the denominator vanishes of a higher order than the numerator or not.

Comment: For some reason i was writing z = 2, but in my mind was working out z = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For quotients of polynomials, you can cancel "like terms" from the numerator and denominator. If a given factor remains in the denominator, then the associated zeroes of that factor are poles. If a factor can be removed, then it is removable.

For example:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{z^2-1}{(z+1)(z+2)}&=\frac{z-1}{z+2}\\
\frac{z^2-3}{(z+1)(z+2)}&=\frac{z^2-3}{(z+1)(z+2)}\\
\frac{(z+2)(z^2-1)}{(z-1)(z+1)}&=z+2
\end{align}$$
In the first, $z+1$ is removable, while $z+2$ represents a pole. In the second, both points are poles. In the third, both are removable. The reason this method is viable is that the functions are the same as their simplified forms in areas away from the singularities.

For other forms (trigonometric functions and other non-polynomials), you can determine whether it is a pole by finding if the limit exists at the point. It is important to be able to tell when this will happen, so brushing up on limit techniques will help a lot.